# Having an issue with where to call input validity checks

Tags: java, function, input

I am having an issue where it isn't checking the validity of user input correctly.  It breaks if I input a letter or string as a choice instead of looping through and asking again.  I'm pretty sure that I have my functions, isDouble and isInt, correct and it's more a matter of placement.  Advice?

```
public class Main 
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        displayMenu();

        int entryChoice = scan.nextInt();

        while (entryChoice != 9) 
        {
            System.out.println(userSelection(entryChoice));

            displayMenu();
            isInt(entryChoice);
            entryChoice = scan.nextInt();
        }

        scan.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static boolean isDouble(double x)
    {
        double userInput = x;
        try 
            {
                userInput = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
                return true; 
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException ignore) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.  Try again.");

                return false;
            }
    }
    public static boolean isInt(int x)
    {
        int userInput = x;
            try 
            {
                userInput = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
                return true;
            } 
            catch (NumberFormatException ignore) 
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                return false;
            }
    }

    public static void displayMenu() 
    {
        System.out.println("Please select from the following choices:");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1) Addition");
        System.out.println("2) Subtraction");
        System.out.println("3) Multiplication");
        System.out.println("4) Division");
        System.out.println("5) Raise to a Power");
        System.out.println("6) Square Root");
        System.out.println("7) Store a Number");
        System.out.println("8) Recall Stored Number");
        System.out.println("9) Exit Program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your choice here: ");
    }

    public static double userSelection(int entryChoice) 
    {
        double result = 0;
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;

        if (entryChoice == 6) 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter one number: ");
            x = scan.nextDouble();
        } 
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers seperated by a space");

            x = scan.nextDouble();
            y = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        switch (entryChoice) 
        {
            case 1:
                result = x + y;
                break;

            case 2:
                result = x - y;
                break;

            case 3:
                result = x * y;
                break;

            case 4:
                if (y == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("Can't divide by zero.  Please enter another number.");
                    y = scan.nextDouble();
                    result = x / y;
                }
                else 
                {
                    result = x / y;
                }
            break;

            case 5:
                result = Math.pow(x, y);
                break;

            case 6:
                result = Math.sqrt(x);
                break;

            case 7:
                //store a number
                break;

            case 8:
                //recall a stored number
                break;

            case 9:
                result = 0;
                break;
            default:

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assuming that the user will give you a number for entryChoice. If I press a ltter for the first time, it will throw InputMismatchException

Comment: Plus make use of hasNext... API. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: The more I read your code the more confused I get about what you're trying to do here. What is `isInt()` supposed to do?  What is the purpose of the `int` you're passing into it?  Why do you have this sort of validation method at all, when you're already guaranteed an `int` from calling `nextInt()` on your `Scanner`?

Comment: I've figured it out.  I'm just reading in strings and parsing them into ints instead.  Thank you for trying to read my bad code! :(  I don't know how to close a question though...haha

Comment: Doing that parsing yourself is still not the best way to go about this.  I posted an answer which I think addresses that point.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pretty sure that I have my functions, isDouble and isInt, correct and it's more a matter of placement.

You don't.

Your `isInt()` method ignores its parameter, reads a new value from the scanner and checks to see if it's a number, and doesn't return the new value, whether or not it's a number.

In any case, the `Scanner` class you are using to collect user input already does this sort of validation for you.  You started in the correct direction with

```
int entryChoice = scan.nextInt();
```

but it's dangerous to try to get a token from a `Scanner` without first checking to see if it has one for you to get.

If you look at the [API docs for `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), you'll see a whole list of `nextFoo()` and `hasNextFoo()` methods.  These are meant to be used together.

Generally what you want is a loop which prompts the user for the desired input until they give it, like this:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    while (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
        scan.next(); // throw away non-numeric input
        System.out.println("Please enter a number");
    }
    System.out.println("User entered: " + scan.nextInt());
```

This will end up re-prompting the user until they give you a number:

> Please enter a number
>   apple
>   Please enter a number
>   fox
>   Please enter a number
>   bear
>   Please enter a number
>   42
>   User entered: 42

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code,However i did many changes.Wish this help you little.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
static int entryChoice = 0;
static boolean tester = true;
static double result;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayMenu();

    boolean check = isInt(entryChoice);
    while (check && entryChoice != 9) {
        result = userSelection(entryChoice);
        System.out.print(result == 0 && !tester ? "" : result + "\n");
        if (!tester)
            break;

    }

    scan.close();
    System.exit(0);
}

/*
 * public static boolean isDouble(double x) {
 * 
 * try { x = Double.parseDouble(scan.next()); return true; } catch
 * (NumberFormatException ignore) { System.out.println(
 * "Invalid input.  Try again.");
 * 
 * return false; } }
 */

public static boolean isInt(int x) {

    try {
        x = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
        entryChoice = x;
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input");
        System.err.println("program will be terminated!");
        tester = false;
        return false;
    }
}

public static void displayMenu() {
    System.out.println("Please select from the following choices:");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("1) Addition");
    System.out.println("2) Subtraction");
    System.out.println("3) Multiplication");
    System.out.println("4) Division");
    System.out.println("5) Raise to a Power");
    System.out.println("6) Square Root");
    System.out.println("7) Store a Number");
    System.out.println("8) Recall Stored Number");
    System.out.println("9) Exit Program");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter your choice here: ");
}

public static double userSelection(int entryChoice) {
    double result = 0;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;

    if (entryChoice == 6) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter one number: ");
            x = scan.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ignore) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input");

        }
    } else {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter two numbers seperated by a space");
            x = scan.nextDouble();
            y = scan.nextDouble();
        } catch (InputMismatchException ignore) {
            System.err.println("Invalid input,program will be terminated !");
            tester = false;
            // return ;

        }
    }
    switch (entryChoice) {
    case 1:
        result = x + y;
        break;

    case 2:
        result = x - y;
        break;

    case 3:
        result = x * y;
        break;

    case 4:
        if (y == 0 && tester) {
            System.out.println("Can't divide by zero.  Please enter another number.");
            try {
                y = scan.nextDouble();
            } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                System.err.println("invalid input, program will be terminated");
                tester = false;
            }
            result = x / y;
        } else if (tester) {
            result = x / y;
        }
        break;

    case 5:
        result = Math.pow(x, y);
        break;

    case 6:
        result = Math.sqrt(x);
        break;

    case 7:
        // store a number
        break;

    case 8:
        // recall a stored number
        break;

    case 9:
        result = 0;
        break;
    default:

    }
    return result;
}
}
```